# Android Shape - Gradient should go to the right side

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, shapes

**What I try to do**

---

I'm trying to create a Backgroud-Shape for my App. For This I created a gradient witch starts in the middle, but I want that it starts on the right side. You can imagine you this like the gradient comes in from the right side.

**Question**

---

What do I need to change in my Shape or Gradient that this works?

**Code**

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">



    <gradient android:gravity="right" android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="280"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF" android:endColor="#CBCBCB" /><!--   #e0dede" -->
</shape>
```

**Image**

---

This how it looks at the moment!

[image]

Like you see the gradient is in the middle, I want that exactly this gradient starts from the right side into the middle of the screen.

Comment: can you please post images of what you want and what you are getting?

Comment: Picture added, hope it helps!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this and see the magic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient android:layout_gravity="right" android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="280"
        android:centerX="100%" android:centerY="50%"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF" android:endColor="#CBCBCB" /><!--   #e0dede" -->
</shape>
```

Tags `android:centerX` and `android:centerY` lets you start your gradient from any point on your screen.You just need to give related % values as i did here.It worked like magic for me!

I didn't change other tags settings of your code but you will have to change the radius as per how much white portion you need to make visible.

Hope,It helped.

Comment: How about linear gradient?

Comment: For those that have issues w/ gradient not rendering on Lollipop, you may need to create another drawable to put in your drawable-v21 folder (with radius specified w/ `dp` or `%p` units), per https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77862